# Selecting only mixed attributes (house numbers blended with other characters and symbols) in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

In ArcGIS, I have an attribute table with house numbers, i.e. numeric and mixed.

I want to select only mixed house numbers.

Mixed means house numbers blended with other characters and symbols, e.g. 65g, 0665, 75-a, a-b, 44-65 etc.

Comment: [@Rakesh reddy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127744/rakesh-reddy), can you please show a piece of your data? I am just curious what kind of addresses it is possible to find in your attribute table, how scattered they are.

Comment: Moreover [Rakesh reddy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127744/rakesh-reddy), I am curious about numeric values, which range do they belong to?

Comment: @BERA but also has a leading zero ... `0665`

Comment: What sort of database or workspace is your data in?  If it is an SQL SDE, you can use `ISNUMERIC()` in your SQL query (see my answer below).  However, this will not work for other kinds of workspaces (and there are some caveats in that answer depending on your data and requirements).

Answer (score 1):

You can use arcpy and the string [isdigit method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm):

> The method isdigit() checks whether the string consists of digits
>   only.

If the string is not all digits, object id is added to a list. Then the list is used in select by attributes:

```py
import arcpy

table = r'Houses' #Change to match the name of your layer in table of contents of ArcMap
adress_field_name = 'Adress' #Change to match the name of your adress field

oid_field = arcpy.Describe(table).OIDFieldName
oids_to_select = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,[adress_field_name,oid_field]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if not row[0].isdigit(): #if you also want records starting with zero use: if (not row[0].isdigit() or (row[0].startswith('0') and row[0].isdigit())):
            oids_to_select.append(row[1])

sql = """{0} IN({1})""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(table, oid_field),','.join([str(oid) for oid in oids_to_select]))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=table, where_clause=sql)
```

Execute in Python window with the feature class added to the map:
[image]

Comment: [@BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/32958/bera), am I correctly understand that solving this task through the usual **Select By Attributes** is too complicated?

Comment: @Taras I dont know how to do it using only SQL, probably possible but to difficult for me

Answer (score 1):

If your workspace is an MS SQL database (or other SDE?) try this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=table, where_clause = "ISNUMERIC( fieldName) = 0")
```

I haven't tested this thoroughly, but it works on a simple dataset I tested with.

NB:  Records which had a decimal point and/or a leading "-" may be considered numeric.  So it depends on if your data has such values and if you want them included or not.

Documentation is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

This will not work on file GDBs or shapefiles.